# Enumerate formulas

Tags: align

I'm writing a math paper in LaTeX and for math formulas I'm just using `$$math formula$$`. Is is possible to numerate formulas? Or do I have to you use some specific commands such as `align`?

Comment: You should use the `equation` or `align`, etc, environments. By the way, [you should never use `$$ $$` for displayed equations but rather `\[ \]`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Answer (score 21):

For inline math use `$...$` (or `\( ... \)`). For display math style equations, if you use `aligned` then alignment with `enumerate`'s `\item` works better:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
    E &= mc^2 \\
    F & = ma
\end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
    E &= mc^2 \\
    F & = ma
\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Why is there a `\,` space at the beginning of the `aligned` environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98482) might be interesting if one notices the different spacing before `y = mx + b` and the `aligned` blocks.

Comment: how can we create the same with the numbered equation?

Comment: @JaiKumar: Sorry for the delayed response, but I was going to suggest posting a new question as it is not clear from your comment what the requirements were, but looks like you already did that.

Comment: @PeterGrill. Thank you very much for your response. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546433/137779

Answer (score 19):

Vanilla displayed equation idioms:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The \verb|equation| environment creates numbered formulas you can
label and refer to elsewhere:
%  this commented blank line prevents start of a new paragraph
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pythagoras}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2 .
\end{equation}
%  this commented blank line prevents start of a new paragraph
Equation~\ref{eq:pythagoras} is the heart of the Pythagorean theorem.

Use the \verb|\eqref| macro to put parentheses around equation
references: \eqref{eq:pythagoras}.

For equations with no numbers, use \verb|equation*|:
%
\begin{equation*}
2 + 2 = 4 .
\end{equation*}

For multiline formulas, use \verb|align| or \verb|align*|:
%
\begin{align}
e^{i\pi} & = \cos(\pi) + i\sin(\pi) \notag \\
         & = -1 .
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** `TeX` will complain if it sees a blank line before the `\end` of one of these environments. Debugging that error message is difficult since you tend to think that `TeX` automatically does the right thing with white space. See
["File ended while scanning use of \align*"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102748/file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-align)

Comment: +1 I think this is what the OP was asking for. Just one edit needed- never put blank lines before a displayed equation, it throws the spacing off. Either remove them, or put in a comment symbol

Comment: @cmhughes Added the `%` and will remember to do that in my own documents from now on.

Comment: @EthanBolker To complete cmhughes’ statement: Use blank lines if you want to start a new paragraph (blank lines after displayed math is only correct if it ends a paragraph). Do not use blank lines to structure your input.

Comment: You mean: "Do not use blank lines to format your source file." Of course, the input (in the sense of content) should be structured in paragraphs and therefore needs blank lines (or `\par`s).

Comment: @Toscho Of course you can use blank lines to separate paragraphs. You just can't put them right before `\end{equation}` or `\end{align} - the compiler will complain. Don't use them right after unless you want to start a new paragraph there. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: What if, depending on document section, I would like to numerate them as (1.1), (1.2),...;  (2.1), (2.2),(2.3),... etc. ? How do I do that?

Comment: @Kusavil Search for "numberwithin" at  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics