# LaTeX - hspace all equations globally

Tags: equations, preamble

I'm writing my master thesis and have some problems with the setup of the latex.

I want to tabulate(hspace) every equation.

I don't want it to start at the left site or be centered.

Can I somehow indicate a start position for the equations globally in the preamble?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Indent math blocks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102297/5764)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Its easier to solve with a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). that illustrates your problem. Starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. See problem with the given answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the value of `\mathindent`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
 \setlength\mathindent{4pc}

\begin{document}

\noindent This is for test
\begin{equation}
  a+b=c
\end{equation}

\setlength\mathindent{12pc}
\begin{equation}
  d = e + f
\end{equation}

\setlength\mathindent{0pc}
\begin{equation}
  a + b + d =c + e + f
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added:*

I've simplified the code of your `preamble.tex`,  as there were many packages multiloaded:

```
\documentclass[article,12pt, onecolumn, twoside, titlepage, openright]{memoir}
%documentclass{report} - For longer reports containing several chapters, small books, thesis, ...
%documentclass{book} For real books

\providehyphenmins{danish}{22}
\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}%bedreorddeling
%\hyphenation{dette ord bliver aldrig ombrudt af LaTeX}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\chapterstyle{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fourier}
%\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{ulem} % â¬â¬ Figurer og tabeller Â floats â¬â¬ %
\usepackage{flafter}    
\usepackage{multirow}   % Fletning af rÃŠkker
\usepackage{hhline}     % Dobbelte horisontale linier
\usepackage{multicol}    % Fletning af kolonner
\usepackage{pdfpages}           % Gør det muligt at inkludere pdf-dokumenter med kommandoen \includepdf[pages=]{fil.pdf}
\pretolerance=2500              % Gør det muligt at justre afstanden mellem ord (hÃžjt tal, mindre orddeling og mere space mellem ord)
\usepackage{wrapfig}            % Indsættelse af figurer omsvøbt af tekst. \begin{wrapfigure}{Placering}{StÃžrrelse}
%\usepackage{wraptable}             % IndsÃŠttelse af tabeller omsvÃžbt af tekst.
\usepackage{placeins}
% â¬â¬ Matematiske formler og maskinkode â¬â¬
\usepackage{stmaryrd}   % Bedre matematik og ekstra fonte
\usepackage{gensymb}%symbol for grade tegn
\usepackage{textcomp}   % Adgang til tekstsymboler

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\textbf{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{mathtools}          % Udvidelse af amsmath-pakken.
\usepackage{eso-pic}            % Tilføj billedekommandoer på hver side
\usepackage{lipsum} 
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{varioref} %henvisninger med sidetal
%\usepackage{fancyref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[font={small, it},labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption} %lille og kusiv tekst ved tabel og figur
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%giver mulighed for selv at vælge om det skal være a,b,c eller 1,2,3 eller andet som skal være nummerator for listen.
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}   %ingen indryk efter afsnit      
\usepackage[margin=3cm, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[numbers,round,comma, sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{url}

 \usepackage{wasysym}

%Pakker der anvendes til tegning af figure
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{structuralanalysis}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\setcitestyle{square}

%%HVAD BETYDER DETTE?
%%\copypagestyle{outer}{headings}
%\makeoddhead{outer}{}{}{}
%\makeevenhead{outer}{}{}{}
%\makeoddfoot{outer}{}{}{\thepage}
%\makeevenfoot{outer}{\thepage}{}{}
%\copypagestyle{plain}{outer}
%\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}
%\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
%\pagestyle{outer}
%\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{outer}

%%Orddeling:
\hyphenation{}
\hyphenation{}
\hyphenation{}
\hyphenation{}
\hyphenation{}
\hyphenation{}
\hyphenation{}
\hyphenation{skad-ede}
\hyphenation{pa-ra-met-rene}
\hyphenation{has-tig-hed-erne}
\hyphenation{ac-ce-le-ro-met-er-et}
\hyphenation{ud-før-es}
\hyphenation{am-pli-tud-en}
\hyphenation{bjælk-en}
\hyphenation{u-af-hængig}
\hyphenation{sving-ning-er}
\hyphenation{di-men-sion-er-ne}
\hyphenation{kom-po-nent-er}
\hyphenation{me-to-de}
\hyphenation{sys-tem-et}
\hyphenation{af-vig-el-sen}
\hyphenation{sys-tem}
\hyphenation{sving-er}
\hyphenation{sys-tem-ets}
\hyphenation{egen-fre-kvens}
\hyphenation{ænd-res}
\hyphenation{flyt-ning-er}
\hyphenation{in-di-ker-er}
\hyphenation{rand-be-ting-el-ser-ne}
\hyphenation{last-en}
\hyphenation{Esbjerg}
\hyphenation{Danmark}
\hyphenation{u-lyk-kes-last-er}
\hyphenation{på-gæld-en-de}
\hyphenation{æn-dring-en}
\hyphenation{kon-struk-ti-on-ens}
\hyphenation{rekt-an-gu-lær}
\hyphenation{for-ret-ning-er}
\hyphenation{fro-kost-rum}
\hyphenation{ba-sis-vind-has-tig-hed-en}
\hyphenation{las-ter}
\hyphenation{jern-be-ton-pæ-le}
\hyphenation{ned-bøj-nings-be-regn-ing-er}
\hyphenation{af-græns-ning-er}
\hyphenation{pa-ral-lel-o-gram-for-met}
\hyphenation{fo-re-kom-mer}
\hyphenation{beton-sandwich-ele-ment-er}
\hyphenation{beton-sandwich-ele-ment-er}
\hyphenation{fag-om-råd-er-ne}
\hyphenation{do-ku-men-ta-tion}
\hyphenation{do-ku-men-ta-tions-rap-port-er}
\hyphenation{bygge-pro-gram}
\hyphenation{pro-jek-te-ring}
\hyphenation{ele-ment-er}
\hyphenation{an-vend-el-ses}
\hyphenation{følg-ende}
\hyphenation{Skagerrakvej}
\hyphenation{Tag-kon-struk-tion-en}
\hyphenation{kon-struk-tions-del}
\hyphenation{Element-er-ne}
\hyphenation{bag-pla-de}
\hyphenation{fa-bri-ka-tions-hal-len}
\hyphenation{op-luk-ke-lige}
\hyphenation{op-fyld-er}
\hyphenation{dob-belt}
\hyphenation{våd-rum-mene}
\hyphenation{luft-lyds-i-so-le-ring}
\hyphenation{lyd-i-so-lere}
\hyphenation{kon-struk-tion-en}
\hyphenation{und-er-søg-es}
\hyphenation{vir-ke-må-de}
\hyphenation{byg-her-res}
\hyphenation{Eurocodes}
\hyphenation{fun-da-ment-et}
\hyphenation{fun-da-ment-er-ne}
\hyphenation{ka-rak-te-ris-tis-ke}
\hyphenation{tag-et}
\hyphenation{kon-struk-tioner}
\hyphenation{skab-es}
\hyphenation{Projekt-rapportens}
\hyphenation{appen-diks}
\hyphenation{hen-vis-er}
\hyphenation{Billund}
\hyphenation{and-et}
\hyphenation{giv-et}
\hyphenation{dimension-e-ring}
\hyphenation{cykel-stier}
\hyphenation{for-klares}
\hyphenation{Natur-typ-er}
\hyphenation{frednings-om-kreds-en}
\hyphenation{fig-ur}
\hyphenation{skovbryn-ene}
\hyphenation{projekt-e-ring}
\hyphenation{motor-trafik-veje}
\hyphenation{be-virk-er}
\hyphenation{re-gi-o-nal-plan-er}
\hyphenation{om-rå-de}
\hyphenation{vej-net}
\hyphenation{ind-del-es}
\hyphenation{ænd-ring}
\hyphenation{der-es}
\hyphenation{ka-te-go-ri-en}
\hyphenation{kom-mune}
\hyphenation{del-tag-er}
\hyphenation{Vejdirektoratet}
\hyphenation{frem-tidig-e}
\hyphenation{for-skel-lige}
\hyphenation{pro-jekt-eres}
\hyphenation{linje-føring-er}
\hyphenation{ter-ræn-over-flad-en}
\hyphenation{fred-et}
\hyphenation{for-an-stalt-ning-er}
\hyphenation{tag-es}
\hyphenation{ænd-ring-er}
\hyphenation{be-tyd-er}
\hyphenation{bolig-er}
\hyphenation{søg-es}
\hyphenation{linje-føring-en}
\hyphenation{Kommune}
\hyphenation{tra-fik-sik-ker-hed-en}
\hyphenation{ø-ko-no-mi}
\hyphenation{ek-sis-te-ren-de}
\hyphenation{tra-fikant-erne}
\hyphenation{be-skriv-es}
\hyphenation{køre-tøj-ernes}
\hyphenation{giv-er}
\hyphenation{kend-es}
\hyphenation{fak-tor-er}
\hyphenation{ind-en}
\hyphenation{kør-sels-om-kost-ning-erne}
\hyphenation{tab-el}
\hyphenation{barriere-om-kost-ning-erne}
\hyphenation{nu-vær-ende}
\hyphenation{luft-for-u-rening-en}
\hyphenation{tab-el-op-slag}
\hyphenation{stræk-ning-en}
\hyphenation{has-tig-hed}
\hyphenation{barriere-om-kost-ning-er}
\hyphenation{ud-regn-es}
\hyphenation{an-be-fal-ede}
\hyphenation{grund-et}
\hyphenation{ter-ræn-et}
\hyphenation{has-tig-heds-grænse}
\hyphenation{flyd-en-de}
\hyphenation{nog-en}
\hyphenation{Billundvej}
\hyphenation{for-ud-sæt-ning-er}
\hyphenation{an-giv-et}
\hyphenation{u-af-hængigt}
\hyphenation{ind-flyd-el-se}
\hyphenation{høj-der}
\hyphenation{hinan-den}
\hyphenation{tra-fikant-er-nes}
\hyphenation{in-for-mer-er}
\hyphenation{del-es}
\hyphenation{land-lev-ende}
\hyphenation{ud-form-ning-en}
\hyphenation{be-regn-es}
\hyphenation{vend-stræk-ning-en}
\hyphenation{til-hør-ende}
\hyphenation{grund-vands-stand-en}
\hyphenation{før-er}
\hyphenation{fjern-e}
\hyphenation{cir-ku-la-ti-ons-areal-et}
\hyphenation{køre-tøj-er}
\hyphenation{spærre-flad-e}
\hyphenation{vej-ben-et}
\hyphenation{bi-drag-er}
\hyphenation{Sam-tidig}
\hyphenation{find-es}
\hyphenation{Geologi}
\hyphenation{om-råd-er}
\hyphenation{jord-ens}
\hyphenation{de-for-ma-tions-egen-skab-er}
\hyphenation{an-vend-es}
\hyphenation{over-flade-vand}
\hyphenation{ler-jords-art-er}
\hyphenation{skyld-es}
\hyphenation{Des-ud-en}
\hyphenation{vej-pro-jekte-ring}
\hyphenation{geo-tek-niske}
\hyphenation{jord-en}
\hyphenation{slid-styr-ke}
\hyphenation{ned-bryd-es}
\hyphenation{under-bund-en}
\hyphenation{op-land-et}
\hyphenation{Op-land-ets}
\hyphenation{af-strøm-ning-en}
\hyphenation{Af-vand-ings-sys-tem-et}
\hyphenation{bas-sin-et}
\hyphenation{be-fæstel-sen}
\hyphenation{ad-mi-ni-stra-tions}

%%Til appendix - når det skal laves
%\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Appendices}
%\newlistof{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
%\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}
%
%\pretitle{\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries}
%\title{\HUGE{Bilag}}
%\posttitle{\par\vskip1em{\normalfont\Large Projektering af en fabrikationshal\\
%\normalsize Gruppe B4-1-F15 \par\vfill}\end{center}}
%\author{Katrine Hansen, Mille Stagelund Preston, Signe Høeg Guldbrøn,\\
%Anders Malund Dammark Jensen og Kenneth Sørensen}
%\date{\vfill Aalborg Universitet Esbjerg\\
%25. marts 2015 \large}
```

And this is the test file (`P8.tex`):

```
\include{preface/preamble}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{0.5cm}
{\HUGE \bfseries {Analysis of structural behaviors \\
in a thin-walled beam }}\\
{\par\vskip 1em{\normalfont\Large\scshape }
\vspace{5mm}
Structural and Civil Engineering \& Mechanical Design \\ BM1-1-E16 \\ Aalborg Universitet Esbjerg}\\
\vspace{20mm}

\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{figure/frontcover.png} \\
\vspace{4cm}
\small Katrine Hansen, Signe Høeg Guldbrøn, Abdullah Kacar, Baris Uyar and \\ Joao Pedro Batista Pereira dos Santos \\
\vspace{10mm}
{\large 20. December 2016}
\end{center}

%\clearpage

\cleardoublepage
%\include{preface/titelblad}
%\include{preface/forord}
\cleardoublepage

\startcontents
\printcontents{}{-1}{\chapter*{Table of contents}}

\cleardoublepage

\copypagestyle{outer}{headings}
\makeoddhead{outer}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{outer}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{outer}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{outer}{\thepage}{}{}
\copypagestyle{plain}{outer}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
\pagestyle{outer}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{outer}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathleft}[1][0pt]{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin#1}%
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother
\mathleft[4em]
%\setlength\mathindent{6pc}

\include{afsnit/test}

\stopcontents

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\nocite{inman}
\nocite{cook}
\nocite{brodata}
\nocite{introtilstruk}
\nocite{introtildyn}
\nocite{elementmetode}
\nocite{matlab}
\nocite{be}

%nocite{cite-key} kilden tilføjes selvom den ikke er refereret til
\bibliography{bibtex/litteraturliste}

\end{document}
```

Resulting file:
[image]

Comment: Hello friend.
Your code seems to work on a new document.
But i can't get it to work on mine?
Could you please take a look?
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fuyvy4e6rk4c1aw/AADZEZ7-0-AogRmHSi4JnVfga?dl=0
Define the P8 as master and run it.
the pramble is in the preface folder.
Thx friend.

Comment: @Abdullah Kaçar: Try with  this code (you can change the spacing on the left of course): `\mathleft` now has an optional argument, the length of the horizontal spacing of the left of equations (`0pt` by default).
`\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathleft}[1][0pt]{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin#1}%
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother`.

Comment: hello friend. couldn't get it to work.
best regards.

Comment: With the same files as in dropbox?

Comment: yes friend. . . . .  .

Comment: @Abdullah Kaçar: I've posted the simplified `preamble.tex` and modified `P8.tex`. If it doesn't compile on your system, there's something else, and you should post a minimal (non-)working example.

Comment: Thank you friend it worked!
I really appriciate it ! 
Can i somehow rate you in this website?
Thx. !

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking for some left indent for all display equations, try with

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@mathmargin}{2pc}
\makeatother
```

If not so, please confirm

Comment: Hello friend.
Yes thats exactly what i am looking for.
I tried to use your code:
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}\def\@mathmargin{2pc}
and replaced it with this one:
%\usepackage{amsmath}
But it didn't work.
Best regards.

Comment: you need to tag the \def\@mathmargin{2pc} inside \makeatletter and \makeatother before preamble, i.e., \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}\makeatletter \def\@mathmargin{2pc}\makeatother \begin{document}....\end{document}

Comment: You need to know that `\@mathmargin` is a length, not a macro.

Comment: Hello friend.
I'm new at this so im a little confused.

I should put this:
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
in before preamble which means it should be in the master?

Comment: Here is a minimal example: \documentclass{book}\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}\makeatletter\def\@mathmargin{2pc}\makeatother\begin{document} This is for test\begin{equation}a+b=c\end{equation} \end{document}, hope this is enough...cheers...

Comment: Hello friend.
Is it possible for you to help me fix it via. teamviewer?
I would really appriciate it.
Thx!

Comment: yes, but it is possible only on Sunday, i.e., 1st May, 2017, is it fine for you?

Comment: Yes friend. That would be perfect!
Thx in advance! 
If i get it to work before then i will notify you.
Best regards.

Comment: Sorry, I've mentioned the wrong date :-) it should be 30/4/2017...

Comment: Its okkkk (Y) :)

Comment: @MadyYuvi If you insist in proposing `\def\@mathindent{2pc}`, you're helping nobody.

Comment: Hello friend.
If its okay with you i want to cancel our sunday meeting,  Bernard got it to work for me!
I really appriciate that you would take some time off for me.
Thank you!