# System of equations with tag which has subscript

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, amsmath

Suppose I  have an equation

```
u_t = F(x)
u(0) = u_0
```

I want to put a brace around on the left hand side of both lines and give it a tag with a subscript (eg. P_w) AND I want to be able to refer to this later (by using \eqref) by giving it a label.

Problems:

1. I don't know how to tag something with a subscript in it
2. I don't know how to put it on the LHS

Help appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Look here for hints,  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98397/enumerate-formulas/98401#98401, at the `cases` construction for the brace.

Comment: To assign an arbitrary "tag" instead of a number to an equation, load the `amsmath` package and use the command `\tag{...}`. E.g., you could write `<body of equation> \tag{$P_w$} \label{eq:pw}`; note that the argument of `\tag` is in text mode by default, hence the use of `$...$` to create the subscripted material. Elsewhere in your document, you can then create a cross-reference to this equation with the command `\eqref{eq:pw}`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually tried putting the dollar signs  in the tag but inexplicably got an error. It works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equation tag on the LHS is done by the option `leqno` to the `article` class.

Arbitrary Tags can be set with the commands `\tag{}` and `\tag*{}` (the first has parentheses, the second not).

If you want to refer to it later, you have use `$…$` in the `\tag{}` command instead of `\(…\)`.

Lastly, if you want to treat a set of equations as single object, for example if you want to tag it, you should use the `aligned` environment from `amsmath` package.

The code:

```
\documentclass[leqno,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\tag{$\text{P}_\text{W}$}\label{one}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u_t&=F(x)\\
u(0)&=u_0
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
\paragraph{Some Text} Hello World! \eqref{one} is a d*** good pair of equations.
\end{document}
```

The subscript in the tag can be created by several ways. For example, if you use `xelatex`, you can also use the `xltxtra` package with its `\textsubscript` command, in order to circumvent the use of math inside the `\tag`.