# Placing an object at the end of the line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I'm new in LaTeX and I'm currently faced with a problem of placing an object at the end of the line. E.g.

> {equation} (1.1)

I wish to place (1.1) at the end of the line, and I've searched around trying to find a method to do so but to no avail. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is typically achieved by using an `equation` environment: `\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}`. Is this what you're using?

Comment: No, I don't know what is an equation environment...

Comment: If you don't know, you are missing the basics and should read some introductory material like the »[Dickimaw LaTeX Books](http://ctan.org/pkg/dickimaw)«.

Comment: See the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98397/enumerate-formulas/98401#98401 for examples using the `equation` environment.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and to the wonderful world of `LaTeX` :)