# Equation numbers are not showing

Tags: equations, numbering

I am writing a science report and using the format:

```
\[
\int_{I_0}^I \frac{dI}{I} = ...etc. \label{eqn:myEquation}
\]
```

No labels are printing next to the equations
If I later `\ref{eqn:myEquation}` it gives the subsection number that I am working in, this is the same for multiple equations.
I don't really want to use `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` as there is lots of math and it will become quite cumbersome.
I was under the impression that `\[ \]` was the correct way to enter math mode and label an equation? I have done that before with no problems.

Comment: Related: [Put numbers to equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168534/5764)

Answer (score 4):

`\[` produces an un-numbered math display.

you want

```
\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}
```

To get a numbered equation that you can reference with `\label`/`\ref`