# \begin{align} not working when centering math equation

Tags: align

I've read a few posts here about center math equations and all of them make use  of

`\begin{align} *Math symbols* \end{align}`

Now I've included the `\usepackage{amsmath}` before the begin document line. But I keep getting this error:

[image]

Any ideas guys? I'm a latex noob

Here is some code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Situation 1}

\begin{align}
$J_{(j)} = \sum\limits_{i:r(i,j)=1} ((\theta\textsuperscript{(j)})\textsuperscript{T}x\textsuperscript{(i)} - Y_{i,j})^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\theta_k\textsuperscript{(j)})^2$
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a MWE ([see here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3301/47522)) that illustrates your problem?  A basic program works for me...: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align} x = y \end{align}
\end{document}`

Comment: Take out the `$` around your math... `\begin{align}` puts you in math mode already.

Comment: Equations are centered by default. You need align for multiline equations. You may find useful examples here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98397/enumerate-formulas/98401#98401

Comment: @cslstr do you mind writing up a post so that I can accept the answer? THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX is great for math typesetting; so it's unlikely that a formula like that is so complicated to input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Situation 1}

\begin{equation*}
J_{(j)} = 
  \sum_{i:r(i,j)=1} \bigl((\theta^{(j)})^{T} x^{(i)} - Y_{i,j}\bigr)^2 + 
  \frac{\lambda}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\bigl(\theta_{k}^{(j)}\bigr)^2
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

There should never be `\textsuperscript` inside a formula.

Using `\bigl` and `\bigr` in the first formula makes the parentheses slightly bigger, which is good for reading in this case. Since they are almost necessary in the furst summation, I used them also in the second one, for symmetry.

[image]

The `align` environment is for multiline displays; if you want the equation numbered, then use `equation` instead of `equation*`.

But in any case, the contents of `equation`, `align` and similar environments is already assumed to be math, so adding `$` will give errors.