# Why I can not align this equations?

Tags: align

I could can align first line with other lines

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\dfrac{\partial^2 P_{ijl}}{\partial \tau_l \partial \phi} & = &\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \tau_l}\left(P_{ijl}(1-P_{ijl})\frac{\partial \eta_{ijl}}{\partial \phi}\right) \\

& = &\dfrac{\partial P_{ijl}}{\partial \tau_l}\left(1-P_{ijl}\right)\frac{\partial \eta_{ijl}}{\partial \phi}+\frac{\partial \left(1-P_{ijl}\right)}{\partial \tau_l}P_{ijl}\frac{\partial \eta_{ijl}}{\partial \phi}+P_{ijl}(1-P_{ijl})\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau_l}\left(\frac{\partial \eta_{ijl}}{\partial \phi}\right) \\

& = &  ${P_{ijl}}{(1-P_{ijl})^2}$\dfrac{\partial \eta_{ijl}}{\partial \phi}-P^2_{ijl}\left(1-P_{ijl}\right)\frac{\partial \eta_{ijl}}{\partial \phi}+0 \\

& = &  ${P_{ijl}}{(1-P_{ijl})}(1-{2P}_{ijl})$\dfrac{\partial \eta_{ijl}}{\partial \phi}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please complete your example in order to make it compilable for us. This should contain a documentclass and all packages you need for reproduction of your error.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196 ; do not use `$` in your equation as you are already in math mode. Don't use blank lines in your `eqnarray`.

Comment: Use `align`, not `eqnarray`. This may help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98397/enumerate-formulas/98401#98401

Comment: If i remove $ in my formula, P_{ijl} is Pijl. I do not know why?!

Comment: I used {align}, but I lose first line !!!

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example such that we can copy and paste your example and test it for our self. We cannot see which class you are using or which packages. That stuff matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\pd[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial#3^{#1}}}
\newcommand{\md}[6]{\frac{\partial^{#2}#1}{\partial#3^{#4}\partial#5^{#6}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\md{P_{ijl}}{2}{\tau_l}{}{\phi}{} &=\pd{}{\tau_l}\bigg(P_{ijl}(1-P_{ijl})\pd{\eta_{ijl}}{\phi}\bigg) \\
&=\pd{P_{ijl}}{\tau_l}(1-P_{ijl})\pd{\eta_{ijl}}{\phi}+\pd{(1-P_{ijl})}{\tau_l}P_{ijl}\pd{\eta_{ijl}}{\phi}+P_{ijl}(1-P_{ijl})\pd{}{\tau_l}\bigg(\pd{\eta_{ijl}}{\phi}\bigg) \\
&=P_{ijl}(1-P_{ijl})^2\pd{\eta_{ijl}}{\phi}-P^2_{ijl}(1-P_{ijl})\pd{\eta_{ijl}}{\phi}+0 \\
&=  P_{ijl}(1-P_{ijl})(1-2P_{ijl})\pd{\eta_{ijl}}{\phi}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You find better definitions of the commands in `commath` [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135985/4427)

Comment: You are welcome! Next time, please reduce your code until you get it compilable. Errors like blank lines, missing {} or useless $$ can be found easily. Have fun TeXing.