# Labeling math equations

Tags: equations

In .tex documents, when I am displaying an equation I do this:

```
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
```

And it displays with an equation number off to the right.

But when displaying proofs (where lots of work / equations / formulations may be present in a group), is there a standard convention for how these are to be displayed? Would an entire group be stashed between equation tags (and therefore assigned an equation number, cumulatively), or is there a way to display mathematical work without any particular assignment?

Comment: Starred versions of many math-enviroments produces equateions with no tag , and you can then assign a custom tag with `\tag{<text>}`

Comment: Instead of `\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}`, use `\[`...`\]` or `\begin{equation*}`...`\end{equation*}` if you've loaded [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98397/enumerate-formulas/98401#98401

Comment: For standard conventions on writing math, I really have no idea, but would be very interested in knowing. My guess is that it varies between institutions and locales, but maybe there is a ISO-standard on it, which I in principle believe would be the best one to follow.

I am sure there will be a great answer to this soon.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid this is not a TeXnical question, but rather a stylistic problem. We can discuss *how to implement* a convention, not what convention you should follow.

Comment: There are several conventions in mathematics; some people number each displayed formula, other just those they make reference to; in other fields numbering is rare and just some displayed formulas are tagged for reference.