# Align equation with math-mode components

Tags: math-mode, align

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

%\begin{equation}

%\begin{split}

 $\theta$(\textit{g}$_1$) * ($\theta$(\textit{g}$_2$))$^{-1}$  = $\theta$(\textit{g}$_1$) * $\theta$(\textit{g}$_2^{-1}$) \\
= $\theta$(\textit{g}$_1$ \textit{g}$_2^{-1}$) \\
= $\theta$(\textit{g}) $\in$ \textit{G}, where \textit{g} = \textit{g}$_1$ \textit{g}$_2^{-1}$
%\end{split} 

%\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

1. I'm trying to align the equal signs but remove the comments gives a '}' missing error
2. Is there a way to avoid all the '$' inside the equation?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  the equation environment is *all* math, so putting `$` signs in the individual lines of the equation is not only not needed, but causing trouble.  also, there is no need to specify italic for single letters -- all letters are italic there.  and for text, such as "where", you should enter that as `\text{ where }`; notice the spaces on either side of "where".  these features are provided by `amsmath`; look at the examples in the user's guide: `texdoc amsmath`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98397/enumerate-formulas/98401#98401

Comment: Thx!! That's what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Code is simple:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\theta (g_1)\cdot (\theta(g_2))^{-1}  
    & = \theta(g_1)\cdot \theta (g_2^{-1})    \\
    & = \theta(g_1\textit{g}_2^{-1})                   \\
    & = \theta(g) \in G, \text{ where } g = g_1 g_2^{-1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @AthenaWidget, yes, so called math environments are in LaTeX started with `$`, `\(`, `\[`, `\begin{equation}` (numbered), `\begin{equation*}` (not numbered). Beside this, there is a plenty others math environments (m,odes), determined by `amsmath` or other packages. I suggest you to read some introductory text about LaTeX, for example *No so short introduction to LaTeX 2e* and similar. Also is worth to read https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics.

Comment: Thx!! I saw the comment above as well. I'm very new to this.