# Align multiple equations written with \[ EQN \] format

Tags: align

I am new here, no  idea how latex works, found this format to easily work but I can't use the usual align method with it.

```
\[f(x)=p_n(x)+R_{n+1}(x) \]
\[p_n(x)=f(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)}{1!}f'(x_0)+...+\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}f^(n)(x_0) \]
\[ R_{n+1}(x)=\frac{1}{n!}\int\limits_{x_0}^x (x-t)^n f^{n+1}(t) \ dt \]
```

These are my formulas

I tried using

```
\begin(align)
\[f(x)&=p_n(x)+R_{n+1}(x) \]
\[p_n(x)&=f(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)}{1!}f'(x_0)+...+\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}f^(n)(x_0) \]
\[ R_{n+1}(x)&=\frac{1}{n!}\int\limits_{x_0}^x (x-t)^n f^{n+1}(t) \ dt \]
\end(align)
```

But it gave me a bunch of errors. I am using these packages:

```
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: You should use either the `align` environment OR `\[...\]` but NOT both. In your `align` code, eliminates `\[` and replace `\]` by `\\\`.

Comment: thanks that worked, is there an easy way to change the numbering scheme next to equations rather than have them be 1, 2, 3 etc? for example if I want them to be 1.1 , 1.2, 1.3

Comment: yes, either with `\begin{subequations}` and `\end{subequations}` or `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`, depending on what you want. The first option yields (1a), (1b) and so on while the second gives you (1.x) in section 1, (2.y) in 2 etc.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98397/enumerate-formulas/98401#98401

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna use `equation` environment with the `array` as well, so you can align them on the same vertical line. Here is an example of what it should look like:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
f(x)=p_n(x)+R_{n+1}(x) \\
p_n(x)=f(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)}{1!}f'(x_0)+...+\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}f^(n)(x_0) \\
R_{n+1}(x)=\frac{1}{n!}\int\limits_{x_0}^x (x-t)^n f^{n+1}(t) \ dt \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

The output should be what you're looking for, I hope.

EDIT:

To align them on the `equal` sign, then you might wanna use `align*` and then align with the `&` symbol. Here is an example:

```
\begin{align*}
f(x) &=p_n(x)+R_{n+1}(x) \\
p_n(x) &=f(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)}{1!}f'(x_0)+...+\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}f^(n)(x_0) \\
R_{n+1}(x) &=\frac{1}{n!}\int\limits_{x_0}^x (x-t)^n f^{n+1}(t) \ dt
\end{align*}
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT:

To change the numbering of the equations to 3.1 instead of 1, you can use the `tag` element. Here is an example:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{align*}
f(x) &=p_n(x)+R_{n+1}(x) \\
p_n(x) &=f(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)}{1!}f'(x_0)+...+\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}f^(n)(x_0) \\
R_{n+1}(x) &=\frac{1}{n!}\int\limits_{x_0}^x (x-t)^n f^{n+1}(t) \ dt\tag{3.1}\label{eq:3.1}
\end{align*}
\end{equation}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks that kind of works but I prefer them aligned at the equal sign.

Comment: What is the best practice? to use amsmath or the equation thing you're using?

Comment: I have edited my answer, to suit your needs.

Comment: I have edited my answer again to answer your question in the other comments section.